# How to insert the text from the .txt file into a xml file

Tags: xml, text

This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Data [
<!ENTITY data SYSTEM 'data.txt'>
]>
<Data>
  &data;
</Data>
```

Results in this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <!DOCTYPE Data (View Source for full doctype...)> 
- <Data>
  <event start="Nov 5 2012 00:00:00 GMT" link="http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/onpolitics/watergate/chronology.htm" image="http://www.constitutioncenter.org/timeline/flash/assets/asset_upload_file761_12313.jpg" title="Nixon Elected">Richard Milhous Nixon, the 55-year-old former vice president who lost the presidency for the Republicans in 1960, reclaims it by defeating Hubert Humphrey in one of the closest elections in U.S. history</event> 
  <event start="June 17 2012 00:00:00 GMT" end="Aug 1 1972" link="http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/onpolitics/watergate/chronology.htm" image="http://www.utexas.edu/features/archive/2005/graphics/watergate4.jpg" title="Watergate arrests">Five men, one of whom says he used to work for the CIA, are arrested at 2:30 a.m. trying to bug the offices of the Democratic National Committee at the Watergate hotel and office complex.</event> 
  </Data>
```

Is there anyway to remove the top lines during the process? Or hide them?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Data [
<!ENTITY data SYSTEM 'data.txt'>
]>
```

Comment: explain a bit more. are you just wrapping the file in a signle tag? do you tools you prefer to use? I mean, `echo "<data>" >> file.xml; cat file.txt >> file.xml; echo "</data>" >> file.xml` will work, but thats likely not what you are after. Point being, you need to explain more, and try showing some code that explains what you have tried.

Comment: thanks. please check my additions

Comment: ok, what environment are you working in. *inx, windows, mac? what tools would you prefer to do this in? An xml editor like oXygen, the shell? python?

Comment: windows, and all I'm using is notepad++. pretty new here so what do you recommend?

Comment: can you give an example of your original text file too, also do you have any familiarity with a scripting language such as perl or python?

Comment: there was no txt file before. im creating it to contain the body of the .xml. I have experience with php, html, sql, but none with xml whatsoever

Comment: my final result simply needs to be what the original xml file was. I just need it to automatically update from a SQL server in the exact XML format shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is with an inline DOCTYPE declaration and external entity. This will only help though if your XML parser is able to process the DOCTYPE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Data [
<!ENTITY data SYSTEM 'data.txt'>
]>
<Data>
  &data;
</Data>
```

In this case `data.txt` is a relative path from the location of the xml file, you could also use an absolute path, providing your XML parser could follow it.